# Is there any penalty for constantly reloading the game?

Tags: pc, lisa-the-painful-rpg

In Lisa: The Painful RPG, nearly everything you do in the game has a chance of causing you to lose items, magazines, health, or party members, but whenever you get a negative outcome from resting/gambling/just playing the game, you can easily load up the last save and quickly replay the section until you get a better outcome.

Besides personally knowing that I've cheated just a bit, are there any in-game penalties to doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: nah.
The only real repercussions in this game are connected to Joy-usage.
Have a joy-ful week